# Having problems using malloc

Tags: c, malloc, c-strings

Ran this program in GDB and after it goes through target/replace malloc statement the [1] element is always given an awkward value.

For instance (using GDB):

```
(gdb) p target[0]

$1 = -48 '\320'

(gdb) p target[1]

$2 = 101 'e'

(gdb) p target[2]

$3 = -4 '\374'

(gdb) p target[3]

$4 = -73 '\267'
```

For the other variable, it's value is: replace[1] = 'd'

Why is it doing this? And please let me know if I left out any other critical information.

```
void replace(char** list, int wordLine, int targetAmount)
{
    char** final;
    char* target;
    char* replace;
    int wCounter, cCounter, i, hashCounter = 0, addLetter = 0;
    int copyWord, countChars, numOfWords, finalWords = 0;

    target = (char*)malloc(targetAmount);   //allocating memory for 
    replace = (char*)malloc(targetAmount);  //these char*'s
    // other stuff here
}
```

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of malloc in a c program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`malloc` only allocates memory; it doesn't make any guarantees what the contents will be. If you want to initialise the memory contents with 0s, try [`calloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/).

Answer (score 2):

`malloc` doesn't clear the memory so you get garbage in your allocated blocks. You can use `calloc` to automatically clear the memory or `memset` to clear it manually.